# How to prevent autoconversion to character of the dataframe values when decimal fixer function is applied in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, decimal

(reproducible example given)
When I want to fix decimal places in a dataframe, the values in the converted dataframe becomes character vector. Even though I applied `as.numeric`, I could not get rid of this issue.

```
library(vars)
decy <- function(x, k) format(round(x, k), nsmall=k) # decimal place fixer
decy(1.2356, 2) # 1.24
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5)),nrow=5))
df
coef(VAR(df, p=1, type="none"))[[1]][,1] # class(...): numeric vector
#     V1.l1      V2.l1      V3.l1 
# -1.3283444 -0.6205716 -1.1209751 
decy(coef(VAR(df, p=1, type="none"))[[1]][,1], 3) # class(...): character vector
#   V1.l1    V2.l1    V3.l1 
# "-1.328" "-0.621" "-1.121"
```

**What I want:**

```
decy(coef(VAR(df, p=1, type="none"))[[1]][,1], 3) # class(...): character vector unfortunately
#   V1.l1    V2.l1    V3.l1 
# -1.328 -0.621 -1.121"
```

**What I did:**
**1.**

```
decy(as.numeric(coef(VAR(df, p=1, type="none"))[[1]][,1]), 3) 
# [1] "-1.328" "-0.621" "-1.121"  Still, quota marks persists!
```

**2.**
I added "`stringsAsFactors=FALSE`" inspired from [a SOF question (how to prevent dataframe columns being classed as character instead of numeric)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052167/how-to-prevent-dataframe-columns-being-classed-as-character-instead-of-numeric).

```
library(vars)
set.seed(1)
decy <- function(x, k) format(round(x, k), nsmall=k) # decimal place fixer
decy(1.2356, 2) # 1.24
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5)),nrow=5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df
coef(VAR(df, p=1, type="none"))[[1]][,1] # class(...): numeric vector
#     V1.l1      V2.l1      V3.l1 
# -1.3283444 -0.6205716 -1.1209751 
decy(coef(VAR(df, p=1, type="none"))[[1]][,1], 3) # class(...): character vector
#   V1.l1    V2.l1    V3.l1 
# "-1.328" "-0.621" "-1.121" Still, quota marks persists!
```

The other offered solutions in the above link (`cbind.data.frame`, `sapply(..., as.numeric)`) seems to be problem specific, and I could not apply them in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the following is *not* a nice solution (because: It does not prevent autoconversion, it allows it but later remove the effect of the autoconversion), I will have the following application of `as.numeric` in the eventual place:

```
as.numeric(decy(coef(VAR(df, p=1, type="none"))[[1]][,1], 3))
# [1] -1.328 -0.621 -1.121
```

It is really interesting that the following does *not* solve the problem:

```
decy(as.numeric(coef(VAR(df, p=1, type="none"))[[1]][,1]), 3)
# [1] "-1.328" "-0.621" "-1.121"
```

I do not know why.